The associated script cannot be loaded
I created an asset using obi-rope and exported a unity package but when I imported it in a different project this error popped up!

I tried to re-create the unity package, and I noticed obi-rope is also not visible in the prefab.

So what errors are visible in the console? Do the relevant scripts exist in the project where you've imported your package? Did you ensure you packaged all required dependencies?

There is not error in the console tab, and I think I haven't imported the obi-rope package separately. I will try this.
